# 403 Forbidden error from SprintBoot RestTemplate but working fine from Postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api

With a given token, Postman can hit the Microsoft Graph API successfully, whereas the SpringBoot RestTemplate gives the 403 Forbidden error.

From Postman:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/profile/

Authorization: Bearer <token>
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
```

From SpringBoot Apache Logs:

```
GET /beta/me/profile/ HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer <token>
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8 (I hardcoded it to make everything same as postman)
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept: */*
```

Here is the sample code that I was using:

```java
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        String token = "removed for now";

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setBearerAuth(token);
        httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));
        httpHeaders.setCacheControl("no-cache");
        httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "PostmanRuntime/7.26.8");
        HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<String> exchange = restTemplate.exchange("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/profile/",
                HttpMethod.GET,
                httpEntity,
                String.class);
        return exchange.getBody();
    }
```

I tried several suggestions but couldn't figure it out. Any idea on what might be going wrong?

Comment: Check the accessToken by putting it in https://jwt.ms and see if you have the correct permissions or not.

Comment: I had faced similar issues. Hoping your token is valid, can you try adding `"Content-Type": "application/json"` to the header?

Comment: Yeah.. the token is good.. working fine in postman... Also tried with content-type too... Still I receive 403 for some reason.

Comment: (1) Which AAD flow that you're using in your application? (2) Do you use the same AAD flow for your testing with POSTMAN? (3) Try the above API call in Graph explorer and see still you get HTTP 403 or not

Comment: 1 & 2) As an experiment, I am using Authentication Code Flow in POSTMAN and using the same token for the resttemplate also. Postman works but resttemplate don't. 3) Graph Explorer is working fine. No 403 observed.